# Office 365 activity logs API

Tags: rest, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

Is there any API available for Office 365 API through which i can fetch or monitor logs by using application (console/library)?
I want to monitor login, logout, email received, forwarded etc all the activities happening on Office365 account.

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695706/apis-for-monitoring-office-365) for around one year before. Currently is there any solution for the same?

I need to pass **access_token** in Office 365 Management APIs. How to get that token in **Windows Console/Library** project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn645543.aspx)

**

### Office 365 Management APIs

**
Prerequisites:
Subscription to Office 365 and a subscription to Azure that has been associated with your Office 365 subscription. For more details, see Associate your Office 365 account with Azure AD to create and manage apps.

Overview:
•   The client application authenticates to the Azure AD token issuance endpoint and requests an access token.
•   The Azure AD token issuance endpoint issues the access token.
•   The access token is used to authenticate to the secured resource.
•   Data from the secured resource is returned to the application.

There are four key steps:
1.  Registration in Azure AD
Register both the calling service and the receiving service in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). For detailed instructions, see [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment#bk_Office365Account).

2. Requesting access tokens from Azure AD
   To request an access token, use an HTTP POST to the tenant-specific Azure AD endpoint.
   https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

Request example:

```
POST contoso.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=625bc9f6-3bf6-4b6d-94ba-e97cf07a22de&client_secret=qkDwDJlDfig2IpeuUZYKH1Wb8q1V0ju6sILxQQqhJ+s=&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
```

Response example:

```
{
"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjdkRC1nZWNOZ1gxWmY3R0xrT3ZwT0IyZGNWQSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3NlcnZpY2UuY29udG9zby5jb20vIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zdHMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvN2ZlODE0NDctZGE1Ny00Mzg1LWJlY2ItNmRlNTdmMjE0NzdlLyIsImlhdCI6MTM4ODQ0ODI2NywibmJmIjoxMzg4NDQ4MjY3LCJleHAiOjEzODg0NTIxNjcsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInRpZCI6IjdmZTgxNDQ3LWRhNTctNDM4NS1iZ",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":"3599",
"expires_on":"1388452167",
"resource":"https://service.contoso.com/"
}
```

3. Call the Office 365 Management APIs. The app-only access tokens are passed to the Office 365 Management APIs to authenticate and authorize your application.

Answer (score 3):

[ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) having a feature of pull notifications, check their documentation. It may help you but I'm not sure.

This api doesn't have a stable release, snapshots releases are there.

And check this one also https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response: ews-java-api can not be used in c#. And notification API is work only for mail. Is there any API like Management Activity API?