# Office 365 message trace report by OAuth

Tags: oauth, office365api

I built a simple app based on [Office 365 Reporting web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984347.aspx) and it works great.

I'm trying to use it with OAuth but I can't find any documented way to achieve this.

I create an app in azure, but the *Delegated Permissions* list does not contain anything about reporting services.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855780/3107689),
It doesn't help me for 2 reasons:

1. It require Azure AD for each account, A simple office365 exchange user doesn't need (or want) to [activate the Azure AD](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Register-your-free-Azure-Active-Directory-subscription-d104fb44-1c42-4541-89a6-1f67be22e4ad).
2. I could not find the message trace log under the Management API

Any idea?

Comment: The answer you referenced is the correct one. It doesn't require an Azure subscription for each account, it requires Azure AD which is included with O365 already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APIs for monitoring Office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695706/apis-for-monitoring-office-365)

Comment: I tried to log in to azure with office 365 admin to authorize my app, and I got a message that I doesn't have azure account.

Comment: You can't login to Azure with your O365 credentials but that isn't what that API requires.

Comment: Anyway - I specifically need access to message trace log. I couldn't find it under the Management API.